# Rest api spring data mvc framework

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue with a method like i have selected is-delete a field in a MySQL table now condition is if value of is-deleted  gets 1  the row must get deleted from list in an android application but data must be saved in database if is delete =0 that table values must show in an application how could we apply this in repository by find all() and access manager file and controller

Comment: I think you have to clarify a bit... this is not strictly a MySQL question, but how to design your app. Tag it with the programming language you're using, how are you connecting to the DB, which framework are you using (spring?) and which code have you tried so far..

Comment: public interface FoodCourtRepository extends JpaRepository {

List<FoodCourtEntity> findAll(isdeleted=false???);

}

Comment: i am working in rest api via spring i have isdeleted a field in a table i need to find if isdeleted =0 in mysql then it show the data in row in a table as well as in application list but if isdeleted=1,the data remains in table in database but does'nt show in list in an application that is soft delete,how could i implement this condition in repository file by using findall()method